# Is there a better way to tokenize some strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, tokenize

I was trying to write a code for tokenization of strings in python for some NLP and came up with this code:

```
str = ['I am Batman.','I loved the tea.','I will never go to that mall again!']
s= []
a=0
for line in str:
    s.append([])
    s[a].append(line.split())
    a+=1
print(s)
```

the output came out to be:

```
[[['I', 'am', 'Batman.']], [['I', 'loved', 'the', 'tea.']], [['I', 'will', 'never', 'go', 'to', 'that', 'mall', 'again!']]]
```

As you can see, the list now has an extra dimension, for example, If I want the word 'Batman', I would have to type `s[0][0][2]` instead of `s[0][2]`, so I changed the code to:

```
str = ['I am Batman.','I loved the tea.','I will never go to that mall again!']
s= []
a=0
m = []
for line in str:
    s.append([])
    m=(line.split())
    for word in m:
        s[a].append(word)
    a += 1
print(s)
```

which got me the correct output:

```
[['I', 'am', 'Batman.'], ['I', 'loved', 'the', 'tea.'], ['I', 'will', 'never', 'go', 'to', 'that', 'mall', 'again!']]
```

But I have this feeling that this could work with a single loop, because the dataset that I will be importing would be pretty large and a complexity of `n` would be a lot better that `n^2`, so, is there a better way to do this/a way to do this with one loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code is so nearly there.

```
>>> str = ['I am Batman.','I loved the tea.','I will never go to that mall again!']
>>> s=[]
>>> for line in str:
...   s.append(line.split())
...
>>> print(s)
[['I', 'am', 'Batman.'], ['I', 'loved', 'the', 'tea.'], ['I', 'will', 'never', 'go', 'to', 'that', 'mall', 'again!']]
```

The `line.split()` gives you a list, so append that in your loop.
Or go straight for a comprehension:

```
[line.split() for line in str]
```

When you say `s.append([])`, you have an empty list at index 'a', like this:

```
L = []
```

If you append the result of the `split` to that, like `L.append([1])` you end up with a list in this list: `[[1]]`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `split()` for every string in loop

Example with list comprehension:

```
str = ['I am Batman.','I loved the tea.','I will never go to that mall again!']

[s.split() for s in str]

[['I', 'am', 'Batman.'],
 ['I', 'loved', 'the', 'tea.'],
 ['I', 'will', 'never', 'go', 'to', 'that', 'mall', 'again!']]
```

Answer (score 1):

See this:-

```
>>> list1 = ['I am Batman.','I loved the tea.','I will never go to that mall again!']
>>> [i.split() for i in list1]  
# split by default slits on whitespace strings and give output as list

[['I', 'am', 'Batman.'], ['I', 'loved', 'the', 'tea.'], ['I', 'will', 'never', 'go', 'to', 'that', 'mall', 'again!']]
```